# Stucked in Hitting a Website via HTTP Connection- Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection

Trying to hit a website but its not getting hit.
I wrote the following code.

```java
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.io.transport.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HTTPFirstAvailable extends UiApplication
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HTTPFirstAvailable theApp = new HTTPFirstAvailable();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public HTTPFirstAvailable()
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new HTTPFirstAvailableScreen());
    }
}

class ConnectionThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {

          ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
          ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
          connDesc = connFact.getConnection("http://www.example.com/login.php?count=786");

          if (connDesc != null)
          {
              HttpConnection httpConn;

              httpConn = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
              try
              {
                  final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

                  UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                  {
                      public void run()
                      {
                          Dialog.alert("Response code: " + 
                                        Integer.toString(iResponseCode)); 
                      }
                   });
               } 
               catch (IOException e) 
               {
                 System.err.println("Caught IOException: " 
                      + e.getMessage());
               }
          }
    }
}     

class HTTPFirstAvailableScreen extends MainScreen
{   
    public HTTPFirstAvailableScreen()
    {
        setTitle("HTTP First Sample");
        add(new RichTextField("Trying to make HTTP connection... \n"));
        ConnectionThread ct = new ConnectionThread();
        ct.start(); 
    }
}
```

Actually want to get a json response from their. but Im stuck in the first step. Explored different forums and searched a lot. I also executed the MDS before launching and it was giving error
But its not getting any hit on the server. May be I am missing some thing.

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: How is `Connector.open("http://example.com;interface=wifi");` supposed to work?

Comment: How is this related to JSON?

Comment: `http://example.com;interface=wifi` is not a valid URL.

Comment: Sorry pasted the wrong code, please let me know now.

Answer (score 0):

I was previously starting the MDS which was installed in the Program File x86 and it was giving error which was preventing the blackberry simulator to hit the webservice. Now I have installed it in under C drive and now its working like a charm!

Just because MDS was giving errors when it was installed in the program files (x86) as security concerns it was not running and giving a error. So uninstall it and install it direct under C root folder and it will work!